# BufferedWriter is not writing text to text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have a `BufferedWriter` which is being used to write to a file which has just been created in the given directory, however, for some reason it is not writing the text that it reads from another file, here is my code:

```
private static final String tempFileDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/TempATM.txt";  
File tempFile = new File(tempFileDir);  //Create temporary file to write new info to
File toRenameTo = new File("VirtualATM.txt");   //filename to rename temp file to
if (!tempFile.exists() && !tempFile.isDirectory()) {
    tempFile.createNewFile();   //Create temp file if it doesn't already exist.
}   
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile, true); //For writing new balance
Writer bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8"));//For writing new balance
String newLineRead = null;
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("VirtualATM.txt");//for reading from file
BufferedReader newBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);//for reading from file
while((newLineRead = newBufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    if(!newLineRead.contains(cardNumberStr)){
        bw.append(newLineRead); //If the line does not contain user entered card number, write line to new file.
        ((BufferedWriter) bw).newLine();
    }else if(newLineRead.contains(cardNumberStr)){
        bw.append(newAccountDetails);   //Write updated account details if the line read contains users account number
        ((BufferedWriter) bw).newLine();
    }
}
File toDeleteFile = new File("dirToWriteFile"); //File path to delete the file.
if(!toDeleteFile.delete()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FATAL ERROR! Could not delete VirtualATM.txt", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    // for if there is an error when deleting file
}
if(!file.renameTo(toRenameTo)){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FATAL ERROR! Could not rename the file to VirtualATM.txt", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);//for if there is an error renaming file
}
```

**Edit:**

I am also having trouble deleting and renaming the text file, could any suggest what may be causing this problem, what `SecurityExceptions` etc. may be preventing `Java` from deleting and renaming a text file (`.txt`) on `Windows 8.1`?

Comment: Tell me, you do use Java 7+, don't you?

Comment: @fge I have done at the end of my code, I just haven't added that in as I have selected a small snippet of my method, or should I be flushing it at a particular time?

Comment: @Grice I am doing it within the program, as you can see I attempt to do it by calling the `.delete()` method and `.renameTo(toRenameTo)` method

Comment: Then use the java.nio.file API and try-with-resources...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either flush the buffer post writing the data to buffer like

```
bw.flush();
```

or close the writer like

```
bw.close();//handle exception if you are not using AutoCloseable feature.
```

Comment: I have called the method `bw.flush()` before writing the data, and still it is not writing to the given text file?

Answer (score 1):

You must either flush the buffer to the disk **after** writing the data using:

```
bw.flush();
```

or / and if you have finished writing the data, you must always close the writer which will automatically flush the data to the disk before closing using:

```
bw.close();
```

Hope this helps. Good luck and have fun programming!

Cheers,

Lofty